# Связка PHP + MySQL - как обновить клиент PHP для MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu

Система - Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.
Установил MySQL 5.7 (5.7.11-1ubuntu14.04) из пакета с оф. сайта mysql.
Потом Apache и PHP (5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14) из оф. репозитория Ubuntu.
Чтобы получить доступ из PHP к MySQL (mysqli_...()) установил php5-mysql. 
Все работает, но обнаружил, что Phpmyadmin выдает предупреждение: "Версия клиентской библиотеки MySQL 5.5.47 отличается от версии установленного MySQL-сервера 5.7.11. Это может привести к некорректной работе."
Обнаружил, что в пакетах Ubuntu есть libmysqlclient20 (версия 5.7.11-1ubuntu14.04), а с php5-mysql установилась зависимость libmysqlclient18 (версия 5.5.47-0ubuntu0.14.04.1).
Попробовал установить libmysqlclient20, пакет установился, но в PHP все равно используется версия 5.5.47-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
Подскажите, как установить правильный клиент MySQL для PHP версии 5.7.11-1ubuntu14.04 или можно не заморачиваться и использовать клиент от MySQL 5.6?

Comment: риторический вопрос: зачем же вам lts-версия, если вы используете стороннее п.о. (цитирую: *из пакета с оф. сайта mysql*)? по поводу *Это может привести к некорректной работе* — ведь правду пишут. то, что вы соорудили, вполне может привести к некорректной работе сервера как комплекса программ.

Comment: Из обновлений нужен только MySQL, все остальное устраивает из пакетов - поэтому LTS, из-за долгосрочной поддержки.

Comment: сторонние пакеты дистрибьюторы не поддерживают. т.е., поддержки у вас, фактически, нет. чем, собственно, и вызван сам ваш вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Если Вы хотите установить в Linux какой-то другой пакет, отличный от того, что есть в репозиториях, то рекомендую обратить внимание на такой ресурс, как [Linux From Scratch](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/). Забиваете в поиск нужный пакет, переходите по ссылке и смотрите...

Там очень хорошо расписано все: и откуда берется пакет, и какие он обязательные и рекомендуемые зависимости имеет, и как его инсталлировать, и с какими ключами и т.д.